# How to boot Slax into text mode

Tags: linux, kernel, text-mode, slax

Older versions of Slax had a boot choice of a text menu.

I want to use it because it is much faster to boot and i only need few commands to start some backups over the network or work with files.

Single user mode is not enough, i want to use multiple terminals via Alt+F1...F5

**Is there a boot menu choice or kernel parameter to boot into text mode only?**

A partial solution is to use Ctrl+Alt+F1 , but still i have to wait for ther slow graphical startup.

The current version only has 3 choices

- boot with permanent changes
- boot fresh
- boot into memory

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomas Matejicek gave me a solution: **delete the 02-xorg.sb files and next numbers**, leave only 01-core.sb, or 01-firmware.sb

Another possibility is to select runlevel 3  by adding "3" to the kernel parameters.